# Supercollider QT5 layout problems

Tags: qt, qt5, supercollider

Supercollider crowds out my text when qt GUI widgets are made either by me or by sc itself.

Text crowding in SC's FFT Inspecter

[image]

I cannot find the proper formatting settings to fix this either in the QT5 settings manager, or in Suppercollider.
Has anyone else experienced or overcome this problem?

Comment: I don't know what supercollider is, but maybe you should set a stylesheet in your top level window or widget: https://thesmithfam.org/blog/2009/09/10/qt-stylesheets-tutorial/ Also, check if it's not only a problem with your Operating System display zoom (DPI) is set to a value higher than 100%?

Comment: I was a little dismayed that the solution might involve changing the display zoom since my screen is actually a little too hi-def and I can't see stuff at 100% zoom, but I tried these options to no avail. In the meantime, I think Ubuntu updated and fixed my problem. At times doing nothing seems to be the best course of action.

Comment: :-) just remembered another time I had a problem like that: the font that was defined in the code was not available on the system, so the OS used a fail over font. Maybe this is the same situation and the Update fixed the missing font.

Comment: Those spacings are not controlled by Qt alas. SC has a nasty mix of its own GUI rendering and Qt... What you see is probably displayed by SC's FlowLayout. The latter doesn't support global style sheets.